# Listview with optional style

Tags: wpf, listview, styles

I have an application that has the option to load a custom theme. In that theme, I have a style for `ListViewItem` that changes the highlight color. In the application I have a `GridView` that has rows that can be double clicked, and looks like:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ClickableRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="RowDoubleClicked" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

...

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ClickableRowStyle}">

... Set up GridRows 

</ListView>
```

The problem I am having is that since the grid above uses its own style, the colors from the theme don't get applied.

I have tried adding BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}". This works if the theme is loaded, however, if the default Windows style is used, I get an exception from the StaticResourceHolder.

Is there a way to get both the look from the theme (if loaded) while still being able to double click the grid rows?

Comment: What exception you getting. If its XAMLParseException, try looking into inner exception of it for exact issue.

Comment: In the designer I get {x:Type ListViewItem} Could not be resolved.

Comment: Strange. Have you given explicit `x:Key` to style in your theme. In case yes, you need to use that name in `BasedOn`

Comment: I have not given the style in the theme an explicit x:Key. The exception only comes up when the theme is not being loaded, as it appears WPF does not have a default ListViewItem style.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to have an optional style and click events at the same time. I set up a loaded event for the list view, and in the loaded event I create a new style using BasedOn if a ListViewItem style already exists.

Xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}" Loaded="ListView_Loaded">

... Set grid rows

</ListView>
```

C#:

```
private void ListView_Loaded(object sender RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListView listView = sender as ListView;

    Style style;
    if(Application.Current.Resources.Contains(typeof(ListViewItem))
    {
        style = new Style(typeof(ListViewItem), (Style)Application.Current.Resources[typeof(ListViewItem)]);
    }
    else
    {
        style = new Style(typeof(ListViewItem));
    }

    EventSetter setter = new EventSetter();
    setter.Event = ListViewItem.MouseDoubleClickEvent;
    setter.Handler = new MouseButtonEventHandler(ListView_MouseDoubleClick);
    style.Setters.Add(setter);

    listView.ItemContainerStyle = style; 
}
```